# JAVASCRIPT: why my two flatten functions doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, callback, higher-order-functions

Im trying to implement flattern with reduce, reduce will use each:

```
function each(collection, iterator) {
    if (Array.isArray(collection)){
      for (var i=0;i<collection.length;i++){
        iterator(collection[i],i,collection)
      }
    }else {
      for (var key in collection){
        iterator(collection[key],key,collection)
      }
    }
  };
    function reduce(collection, iterator, accumulator) {
    var initalizing = arguments.length === 2;
    each(collection,function(value){
      if (initalizing){
        accumulator = value;
        initalizing = false;
      } else {
      accumulator = iterator(accumulator,value);
      }
    });
    return accumulator;
  };
```

As you can see my flatten didn't return all the elements in the array, I want to keep my if statement here but which part should I correct to make the flatten works?

```
  function flatten(array){
  return reduce(array,function(flat,toFlatten){
      if(Array.isArray(toFlatten)){
          return flat.concat(flatten(toFlatten));

          }else{

          return flat.concat(toFlatten);
              }
      },[]);
  };
flatten([[1,2,3],2,3,[3,4,5],5,6]); //
```

Also, if I don't use `Flatten(toFlatten)` I believe this is recursion? instead, I want to use each function to iterate the nested array...but seems like I have some syntax error and it doesn't work:

```
  function flatten(array){
      return reduce(array,function(flat,toFlatten){
          return each(toFlatten,function(item){
             if(Array.isArray(toFlatten)){
                 return array.push(item);
                 } 
              });
              return array.push(toFlatten); 
          },[]);
      };
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this:

```
flattern([1,2,3],2,3,[3,4,5],5,6)
```

You are passing in multiple arguments, not an array.

```
function flattern (a){
    console.log(a);  //[1, 2, 3]
    console.log(arguments);  //[Array[3], 2, 3, Array[3], 5, 6]
}
```

You would need to pass in

```
flattern([[1,2,3],2,3,[3,4,5],5,6]);
```

Comment: thanks, but wheni use each instead of recursion, it seems not working ?

Comment: If it is not more than two deep, it is as simple as: `function flattern (a){ return [].concat.apply([], a); }`

Comment: what if it is two deep?